# python globals: import vs. execfile

Tags: python, module, namespaces

I put a method in a file mymodule.py:

```
def do_something():
    global a
    a=1
```

If I try

```
>>> execfile('mymodule.py')
>>> do_something()
>>> print a
```

I get "1" as I expect.  But if I import the module instead,

```
>>> from mymodule import *
```

and then run do_something(), then the python session knows nothing about the variable "a".

Can anyone explain the difference to me?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second part where you import `mymodule`, the reason why it isn't showing up is that `a` is global to the namespace of `mymodule` as done that way.

Try:

```
print mymodule.a
```

This prints:

```
1
```

As expected.

As per the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#global):

> The global statement is a declaration which holds for the entire
>   current code block. It means that the listed identifiers are to be
>   interpreted as globals. It would be impossible to assign to a global
>   variable without global, although free variables may refer to globals
>   without being declared global.
>
> Names listed in a global statement must not be used in the same code
>   block textually preceding that global statement.
>
> Names listed in a global statement must not be defined as formal
>   parameters or in a for loop control target, class definition, function
>   definition, or import statement.

Comment: You answered the question I asked, of course.  But I messed up my question!  Need to edit.  Sorry.

Comment: @bob.sacamento: My answer is still applicable to your edited question.

Answer (score 3):

[`execfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) without `globals`, `locals` argument, It executes the file content in the current namespace. (the same namespace that call the `execfile`)

While, `import` execute the specified module in a separated namespace, and define the `mymodule` in the local namespace.