# thread exec-utes successfully another python file but doesn't know contained functions

Tags: python, multithreading, function, python-3.x, exec

I created *incl.py* and *ml.py*.  *incl.py* is to be loaded from one of several directories each one containing such a file *incl.py*.  *ml.py* is the "main" loading that *incl.py* via `read()` and `exec()`.  Each *incl.py* is expected to contain a set of functions with the same name and interface but possibly different behaviour.

*ml.py* starts one or more threads.  Each thread should load *incl.py* from its individual directory.  The loading works fine, however, the loaded functions seem to be unknown to the thread.

content of *incl.py*:

```
def printIncluded (parameter):
    print (parameter)
```

content of *ml.py*:

```
import threading

def threadContent (parameter):
    exec (open ("incl.py").read ())
    printIncluded (parameter)

thread = threading.Thread (target = threadContent,  args = (("loaded from thread"),))
thread.start ()
```

As soon as I don't use threading it works, for example with the following content of *ml.py*:

```
exec (open ("incl.py").read ())
printIncluded ("directly loaded")
```

What has to be considered regarding `exec()` when working in threads?

Answer (score 0):

I found a helpful hint at [python globals: import vs. execfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542941/python-globals-import-vs-execfile).

Extending the statement

```
exec (open ("incl.py").read ())
```

to

```
exec (open ("incl.py").read (),  globals ())
```

makes it work. However, it seems that I don't have yet a precise imagination of local and global scopes and why that works. So, the question is still open regarding the aspect 'why'.

Apart from that, my impression from reading a few other answers is that using import is preferred by a couple of true Pythonians but I didn't quite understand why (the 2nd one). At least the coding seems simpler using `read ()` and `exec ()` than constructing long sys path extensions.